# How to set am image using AsyncImage when getting data from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have a repository class, where I create a Firestore call to get an image URL:

```
override suspend fun getImageUrl() = flow {
    try {
        emit(Response.Loading)
        val imageUrl = ref.document(id).get().await().getString("imageUrl")
        emit(Response.Success(imageUrl))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Response.Failure(e))
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel class I have a State object where I set the URL like this:

```
var imageUrlState = mutableStateOf<Response<String>>(Response.Success(null))

init {
    getImageUrl()
}

fun getImageUrl() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.getImageUrl().collect { response ->
            imageUrlState.value = response
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my ProfileScreen I have this:

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(
    viewModel: ImageUrlViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(viewModel.imageUrlState.value) // Doesn't work!!!
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape).width(96.dp).height(96.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

And this what I have done to track the error:

```
when(val response = viewModel.imageUrlState.value) {
    is Response.Loading -> ProgressBar()
    is Response.Success -> Unit
    is Response.Failure -> LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        print(response.e)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the URL correctly from the database, but the image is **not** rendered on the AsyncImage. I checked the URL and it opens correctly in a browser? How to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the reason why Coil request failed you can use `listener`:

```
ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
    .listener(
        onError = { request, result ->
            println(result.throwable)
        } 
    )
```

My assumption is that with `viewModel.imageUrlState.value` you pass `Response` object to Coil, you need to unwrap it and pass the containing URL.